# Posting XML as string in Java, when to flush and close connection?

Tags: java

If I have this piece of code:

```
StringBuilder postData = new StringBuilder();
postData.append(URLEncoder.encode(cxmlContent, "UTF-8"));
byte[] postDataBytes = postData.toString().getBytes("UTF-8");

URL url = new URL(urlString);
URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
// specify that we will send output and accept input
con.setDoInput(true);
con.setDoOutput(true);
con.setConnectTimeout(20000);  // long timeout, but not infinite
con.setReadTimeout(20000);
con.setUseCaches(false);
con.setDefaultUseCaches(false);
// tell the web server what we are sending
con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8" );
con.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(postDataBytes.length));

con.getOutputStream().write(postDataBytes);

// reading the response
InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream());
StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
char[] cbuf = new char[ 2048 ];
int num;
while ( -1 != (num=reader.read( cbuf )))
{
    buf.append( cbuf, 0, num );
}
String result = buf.toString();
```

Do I then still need to use the:

```
con.getOutputStream().flush();
con.getOutputStream().close();
```

Because If I use the `flush` and `close` before the inputreader, then I will not receive any input. But If I use the flush and the close below the inputreader (at the end of the piece of code) then I get this error:

java.net.ProtocolException: Cannot write output after reading input.

Comment: flush to make sure data left buffer, don't close the stream until you're absolutely done.

Comment: unrelated, but why do you URLencode an XML document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Close()
```

call the 
flush() method too. 
So you actually need to only call close and both toghether because they redundant. 
You don't receive data because you apply the close on the stream of the connection. 
I suggest use Outputstreamwriter and Bufferedwriter created from the streams.

Something like this :

```
    OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter( connection.getOutputStream()); 
out.write("string=" + stringToReverse);
 out.close(); 
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( connection.getInputStream())); 
String decodedString; while ((decodedString = in.readLine()) != null) { System.out.println(decodedString); } in.close();
```